# Hyper-V - Multiple VM's, Multiple IP's, 1 NIC?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I am new to server administration and am building a test environment in my home. I am using Windows Server 2008 R2 (64-Bit), What I am wanting to achieve is to create multiple Virtual Machines, have each of those having its own IP Address, although I only have one Ethernet port.

I'm going to have to buy powerline adapters or run a long cable from my server pc to the router (its my parents house and they're fussy so they don't like the second solution). What I want to know before I shell out with another £45 is, Will this be possible using Hyper-V Manager and Windows Server 2008 or will I have to have something totally different set up? The reason I want seperate IP's is so that I can remotely connect to them from my laptop (the Server PC will be put out of the way with no monitor connected)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, each virtual machine can have its own IP address, and this is actually the usual setup in any virtualized environment. The host behaves as if it had a "virtual switch" inside it ("virtual switch" is actually how VMware calls it); VMs are connected to this vitual switch, and its uplink port goes to your physical NIC(s). The end result is exactly the same as having physical machines connected to a physical switch, so yes, of course each one of them can (and should!) have its own IP address.

It's also possible to use VLANs and trunking, but I'm stating this just for completeness of information, as this doesn't seem to be your case; anyway, you *can* even bring multiple VLANs to a host (and thus to the VMs running on it) using a single physical Ethernet port.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to comment it is much appreciated and I feel I have a better understanding now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can assigned multiple IP addresses to a single NIC even without Hyper-V running. With Hyper-V, each virtual instances is provided its own "virtual" NIC which refers back to a physical NIC, which can be a single physical NIC or multiple ones.

Comment: Thank you for the swift response @user48838 I just wanted to check as I have never done this before. So it should definitely work then yes?

Comment: Yes, it will work. Each virtual NIC, on each server, will need its own internal network IP, assigned statically (usually) or dynamically.

Comment: The virtual NICs can be assigned different "modes" of operation as to whether they are bridged, NATted, restricted within an internal virtual network or isolated in limbo. The underlying network configuration for each "mode" will dictate the corresponding IP assignment option(s).

Comment: KCotreau, "Each virtual NIC, on each server," I think you might have meant "physical" instead of "virtual" in the context of what you are trying to convey.

Comment: @user48838 .. I would just like to say that I mean no disrespect to you by not marking your answer a the answer for this however I just feel the it is more beneficial for others to see the other answer marked as the answer because it provides some further detail. I am however extremely grateful for you taking your time to respond

Comment: No problem, you mark what you feel you need to mark.